# C++ Pointers or References

Tags: c++, pointers

My Class `PlaylistTrack` is a subclass of `Track` (extends that class):

```
 #include "track.h"
 #include "album.h"

 class PlaylistTrack : public Track //extends Track Class
 {
   private:
           Album & newAlbum; //or
           Album * newAlbum; //?


   public:
       PlaylistTrack(void);
      ~PlaylistTrack(void);

 };
```

I'm hoping i have the correct syntax.
How do you go about adding a reference or pointer to the Album on which a certain track occurs?

Comment: I'm not sure the design makes sense. I don't see tracks on a playlist being a subset of all tracks. I see that a playlist contains tracks so you would need a Playlist object with a collection of Track objects, imho.

Comment: This is really very broad. Which C++ book are you learning from? I hope it's [one of these](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources).

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur: I don't see that `Track` means "tracks not on a playlist", though I join you in questioning the use of inheritance here.

Comment: Presumably, when a Track is constructed, it can take a reference to the Album it belongs to. So a PlaylistTrack would inherit that constructor, so it would be passed at construction time. Otherwise you would use a Track accessor to set its Album data member, and PlaylistTrack would inherit that accessor as well.

Comment: Looks like the playlist entries should contain an album and a track.

Comment: Read up on Database Theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand exactly what you are asking, but it sounds like you want to have a way to get the album from a PlaylistTrack.

```
class PlaylistTrack : public Track
{
 public:
     PlaylistTrack(Album * owner){ m_owner = owner; }
     Album* getAlbum(){return m_owner;}
 private:
     Album* m_owner;

}

int main()
{

Album albumA;
PlaylistTrack newTrack(&albumA);

//Now the track knows what album it belongs to, but the album does not own the track    yet.
std::cout << "New Track's Album: " << newTrack.getAlbum.getTitle() << std::endl;

//Now the album owns this track
albumA.addTrack(newTrack);

//The PlaylistTrack constructor could add itself to the album if you wanted to I think.

return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is nice code. Thanks for your time :D

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference like this:

```
class PlaylistTrack : public Track //extends Track Class
{
   private:
       Album &album;
   public:
       PlaylistTrack(void);
      ~PlaylistTrack(void);

};
```

or a pointer like this:

```
class PlaylistTrack : public Track //extends Track Class
{
   private:
       Album *album;
   public:
       PlaylistTrack(void);
      ~PlaylistTrack(void);

};
```

Of course, you'll probably want to modify your constructor so that it takes an album and track number (or something along those lines), or at least add accessors for the album and track number.

Comment: In the first example, doesn't the constructor need to initialize the reference in an initialization list?  I always get errors on this.

Comment: Cool, basically i just wanted to know which was which. Thanks :D